# Code of a generator that does not work properly in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, object, iterator

I have the following code of an iterator. Since I have created a separate class meant to iterate through my list, if I put two consecutive for statements that I used to iterate through my object, I should not need to reset the index manually. But, on a global run, it only displays once the elements of my list, and upon multiple iterations, it stops displaying anything, so I think somewhere the resetting of the index does not happen properly. Please use simple code and simple explanations because I am a beginner.

```py
my_list = [1,2,3]    

class Iterator:
    def __init__(self,seq):
        self.seq = seq

    def __next__(self):
        if len(self.seq) > 0:
            return self.seq.pop(0)
        raise StopIteration


class Iterating:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def __iter__(self):
        return Iterator(my_list)

i_1 =Iterating()

for element in i_1:
    print(element)

print()

for element in i_1:
    print(element)

# why does this not work?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because while you're iterating over your `Iterator` you're deleting all elements from your `self.seq` thus when you try to iterate over it second time you're iterating over empty list. You could create temporary list that you'll pop from and just "refill" it every time you finish iterating for further usage.

```
class Iterator:
    def __init__(self,seq):
        self.seq = seq
        self.temp_seq = self.seq.copy()

    def __next__(self):
        if len(self.temp_seq) > 0:
            return self.temp_seq.pop(0)
        self.temp_seq = self.seq.copy()
        raise StopIteration
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that method `pop` modifies list (see [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/datastructures.html#using-lists-as-stacks)):

```py
    def __next__(self):
        if len(self.seq) > 0:
            return self.seq.pop(0) # method pop(0) modifies list
        raise StopIteration
```

When you create new instance `Iterator(my_list)` variable `my_list` is passed by reference.
To fix your could you can create a copy of `my_list`:

```py
Iterator(my_list.copy())
```

Comment: This doesn't fix the problem. You still need to create new instance every time you want to iterate over it.

Comment: @FilipMłynarski, you can try my solution. Replace `return Iterator(my_list)` with `return Iterator(my_list.copy())`. It works for me.